# How to convert a youtube video url to the iframe embed code, using jQuery on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a WYSIWYG textarea, and sometimes user's may enter a youtube url into the box. On the server side, there are html filters to prevent "harmful" code from being saved.

So instead, I'd like to just keep the server code as-is, and run a jQuery document ready event that searches a block of text for a youtube link, and converts it to the iframe embed code.

I'd imagine it would be regex based, but I'm absolutely horrid with regex's (at some point, I really need to sit down and study them).

#### Two types of youtube links:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t-ZRX8984sc
```

or

```
http://youtu.be/t-ZRX8984sc
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This regex will pick up the URLs and replace them with the *embed* markup (just an `iframe` according to what YouTube currently outputs).

```
str.replace(/(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?(.+)/g, '<iframe width="420" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/88Ms2/).

However, this can mangle things such as event handlers attached with old school methods.

It is a bit more complicated, but the *best* way would be work with text nodes only.

That should look something like this...

```
$('body').contents().each(function() {

    // Skip non text nodes.
    if (this.nodeType !== 3) {
        return true;
    }

    // Grab text
    var matches = this.data.match(/(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?(.+)/g);

    if (!matches) {
        return true;
    }

    var iframe = $('<iframe width="420" height="345" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen />', {
        src: 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + matches[1]
    });

    iframe.insertAfter(this);

    $(this).remove();

});
```

Note that this inserts after the entire text node.

Comment: Alex, that works! One problem, the WYSIWYG editor likes to add divs and br's right up against the url the user posts. It still creates the embed, but adds the div or br onto the video id. Are the youtube video id's always the same length? Perhaps the regex could match to a certain length?

Comment: @Chad Are, got it. Try putting a word boundary at the end `\b` or using a character range like `[\w-]`.

Comment: It looks like the video id's are always 11 characters long. How would I add `[\w-]`, using 11 character limit, to the regex you provided? (wow, I hate sounding like such a noob... REALLY need to learn regex's ). Thanks a ton for your help!

Comment: @Chad You shouldn't have to and I wouldn't be so sure if they would *always* be 11 chars. However, if you understand the risks, it would be `[\w-]{11}`.

Comment: This doesn't account for other URL parameters, would you prefer an edit or a new answer? Please see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qtvFH/). +1 either way, thanks!

Comment: the match should read: `var matches = /(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?([^& \n]+)/g.exec(this.data)` since `match()` doesn't capture regex groups

Comment: @iBobo `match()` does, just a bit differently.

Comment: @alex I'm sorry but couldn't make it work using match, so posted what's working for me

Comment: Thanks, I'm using this for NodeBB's YouTube plugin (https://github.com/psychobunny/nodebb-plugin-youtube)


I modified this slightly to work with https links as well:

`var matches = this.data.match(/(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?(.+)/g);`

Answer (score 4):

```
var yturl= /(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?([\w\-]{10,12})(?:&feature=related)?(?:[\w\-]{0})?/g;
var ytplayer= '<iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
str.replace(yturl, ytplayer);
```

Ensure proper operation at the organization of WYSIWYG editor