# Convert a YouTube video URL to embed code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this to convert YouTube URL to embed URL.

```
text(t).html().replace(/(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com)\/(?:watch\?v=)?(.+)/g, '<iframe width="320" height="280" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/$1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>')
```

How can I make it ignore itself?

```
t = $('<div></div>').text(t).html().replace(/(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com)\/(?:watch\?v=)?(.+)/g, '<iframe width="400" height="380" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/$1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>')
```

and an embedded link

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/1adfD9" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Or, In other words, how can I make it work only on links like this and ignore everything else?

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1adfD9
www.youtube.com/watch?v=1adfD9
youtube.com/watch?v=1adfD9
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a youtube video url to the iframe embed code, using jQuery on page load?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168987/how-to-convert-a-youtube-video-url-to-the-iframe-embed-code-using-jquery-on-pag)

Answer (score 174, accepted):

I'd be inclined to simply grab the video ID per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452546/javascript-regex-how-to-get-youtube-video-id-from-url) and use it to formulate your embed markup as you like.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/cH6e8/

```js
function getId(url) {
    const regExp = /^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|&v=)([^#&?]*).*/;
    const match = url.match(regExp);

    return (match && match[2].length === 11)
      ? match[2]
      : null;
}
    
const videoId = getId('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zbYf5_S7oJo');
const iframeMarkup = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/' 
    + videoId + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';

console.log('Video ID:', videoId)
```

[Here's a more elaborate demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/cH6e8/6).

Answer (score 38):

You can get the embed code by using the oembed API. There may be multiple variants of the YouTube URL and using regex may not be an optimal solution.

```
https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=<URL>&format=<FORMAT>
```

example:

```
https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gBrmnB5aOSI&format=json
```

The response you will get is this, from which you can use the HTML data for the iframe:

```
{
"type": "video",
"thumbnail_width": 480,
"provider_name": "YouTube",
"title": "Intro To Live Streaming on YouTube",
"thumbnail_height": 360,
"provider_url": "https://www.youtube.com/",
"version": "1.0",
"height": 270,
"author_name": "YouTube Creators",
"html": "<iframe width=\"480\" height=\"270\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/gBrmnB5aOSI?feature=oembed\" frameborder=\"0\" allow=\"accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture\" allowfullscreen></iframe>",
"author_url": "https://www.youtube.com/user/creatoracademy",
"width": 480,
"thumbnail_url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/gBrmnB5aOSI/hqdefault.jpg"
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I think the simplest solution is this:

```
ytUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DGIXT7ce3vQ"
// replace:
ytUrl.replace('/watch?v=', '/embed/')
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is what I used to convert the YouTube URL to embed and make the video work.

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var str = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1adfD9";
        var res = str.split("=");
        var embeddedUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+res[1];
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
    }
</script>
```

I hope this helps

Comment: This should work well as long as there aren't any other URL parameters. If there are you'll also get the next parameter key as the result of your split function.

Comment: Of course, but you can use limit as the second parameter. 
`string.split(separator, limit)` I hope this help you

Answer (score 7):

I've been using this pair of functions to convert youtube links in a block of html from a wysiwyg editor into embedded iframes.

As with other solutions, this can still mangle some other html in the block.

- works with multiple videos in one block of text
- works with http or https links
- works with both the direct url of the video `youtube.com/watch?v=UxSOKvlAbwI` and the share links `youtu.be/UxSOKvlAbwI`

code:

```
createYoutubeEmbed = (key) => {
  return '<iframe width="420" height="345" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + key + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe><br/>';
};

transformYoutubeLinks = (text) => {
  if (!text) return text;
  const self = this;

  const linkreg = /(?:)<a([^>]+)>(.+?)<\/a>/g;
  const fullreg = /(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(youtube\.com\/watch\?v=|youtu\.be\/)([^& \n<]+)(?:[^ \n<]+)?/g;
  const regex = /(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com\/watch\?v=|youtu\.be\/)([^& \n<]+)(?:[^ \n<]+)?/g;

  let resultHtml = text;  

  // get all the matches for youtube links using the first regex
  const match = text.match(fullreg);
  if (match && match.length > 0) {
    // get all links and put in placeholders
    const matchlinks = text.match(linkreg);
    if (matchlinks && matchlinks.length > 0) {
      for (var i=0; i < matchlinks.length; i++) {
        resultHtml = resultHtml.replace(matchlinks[i], "#placeholder" + i + "#");
      }
    }

    // now go through the matches one by one
    for (var i=0; i < match.length; i++) {
      // get the key out of the match using the second regex
      let matchParts = match[i].split(regex);
      // replace the full match with the embedded youtube code
      resultHtml = resultHtml.replace(match[i], self.createYoutubeEmbed(matchParts[1]));
    }

    // ok now put our links back where the placeholders were.
    if (matchlinks && matchlinks.length > 0) {
      for (var i=0; i < matchlinks.length; i++) {
        resultHtml = resultHtml.replace("#placeholder" + i + "#", matchlinks[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  return resultHtml;
};
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/phlare/j6tjk4tr/)

Comment: i saw this was not working with specific time start in video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B6ZQVXA0IRw&t=796s). Any help for this.

Comment: I’ll see if I can work that in.  Turns out this snippet is mangling links out to YouTube videos that are meant to remain links (inside a fully formed a tag)  so I need to fix that anyway.  It’s on my todo list for today/tomorrow at least

Comment: It does create player from link that has the link as the hypertext
<a href="https://youtu.be/fDVQPBvZOeo">https://youtu.be/fDVQPBvZOeo</a>
if the link is like this <a href="https://youtu.be/fDVQPBvZOeo">video</a>
it leave the link untouched, which is I guess the planing feature in both cases

Comment: its working good but only for ONE div=id, how to change it for classname? `const htmlContent = document.getElementsByClassname(\'post\');//not working`

Answer (score 2):

```
function popYouTubeId(buttonid) {
    var youTubeUrl = $(buttonid).attr('data-url');
    var youTubeId;
    var regExp = /^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/;
    var match = youTubeUrl.match(regExp);
    if (match && match[2].length == 11) {
       youTubeId = match[2];
    } else {
        youTubeId = 'no video found';
   }
   $('#ytvideo').html('<div class="youtubepopup"><a class="closex">x</a><iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/' + youTubeId + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>');
   $('a.closex').click( function(){
       $('.youtubepopup').remove();
   });
}

var buttonid;

$('.videobutton').click( function(){
    buttonid = '#'+$(this).attr('id');
    popYouTubeId(buttonid);
});
```

Some elaboration on isherwood's demo for your consideration. Simplifies, and packs more into the function for multiple use.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slabmedia/n8x9oadh/)

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me on ReactJS

```
<iframe src={`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${url.split('='}[1]&autoplay=false`} controls allowfullscreen />
```

Answer (score 1):

Who needs jQuery. Below is pure javascript code using [`URL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) function to get `v` parameter from YouTube URL and [`insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) from replacing current `<script>` tag with `<iframe>`

```
<script>
const url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qRv7G7WpOoU";
const v = new URL(url).searchParams.get('v');

document.currentScript.insertAdjacentHTML(
  'beforebegin',
  `<h1>Video id=${v}</h1>` +
  `<iframe
      width="480" height="270"
      src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/${v}?feature=oembed"
      allowfullscreen></iframe>`
  );
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't this way of getting the embedded id from desktop links seem easier to understand?

```
 const convertLinkToEmbedId = () => {
    const link = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gBrmnB5aOSI&...";
    return link.substring(link.indexOf("=") + 1, link.indexOf("&"));
  };
```

You can then embed it this way:

```
 <iframe
      width='560'
      height='315'
      src={`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${convertLinkToEmbedId()}`}
      title='YouTube video player'
      frameborder='0'
      allow='accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture;fullscreen;'
    >
</iframe>
```

The problem is that this wouldn't work where there the id isn't between '=' and '&' :(

Answer (score 0):

Created a Angular pipe for this case, which can simply be used wherever needed, it converts the link directly in the template.

HTML template:

```
<iframe
                width="560"
                height="315"
                [src]="PAST_YOUR_YTUBE_LINK_HERE | ytubePipe"
                title="YouTube video player"
                frameborder="0"
                allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
                allowfullscreen
              >
              </iframe>
```

Pipe ts file:

```
    import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'ytubePipe',
  standalone: true,
})
export class YtubePipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  createYoutubeEmbed(key: string): string {
    return `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${key}`;
  }

  transform(url: string): SafeResourceUrl {
    if (!url) {
      return '';
    }

    let videoId: string | null = null;
    const fullreg =
      /(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(youtube\.com\/watch\?v=|youtu\.be\/)([^& \n<]+)(?:[^ \n<]+)?/g;
    const match = fullreg.exec(url);
    if (match && match.length > 4) {
      videoId = match[4];
    }

    if (videoId) {
      const safeUrl = this.createYoutubeEmbed(videoId);
      return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(safeUrl);
      // return safeUrl;
    }

    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
    // return url;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 @if (path.Contains('&'))
                            path = path.Split('&')[0];

                <iframe width="690" height="400" src="@Model.YourModelNameHERE.Replace("watch?v=","embed/")" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

C# Razor pages solution!